# put location.href in a variable with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've put tha value of location.href in a variable and i want to bound that variable in a onclick of a buuton that i added it on a div with inner.html

here is my code:

```
  function absence(id)
          { 
                var goToConsulter ="<?php echo site_url('index.php/Enseignant/consulter_presence/'); ?>"+id;

             document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='location.href='"+ goToConsulter +"'> Consulter</button><button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='marquer("+id+")'>Marquer</button>";  

          }
```

but it shows an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }, i test with alert function the parameter of the function and it works so i'm certain that the problem is in the bound, so could you plz tell me what went wrong 
thank you

Comment: What is outputted from `<?php echo site_url('index.php/Enseignant/consulter_presence/'); ?>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should wrong here `onclick='location.href='"`

It should be `onclick='location.href=\""+ goToConsulter +"\"'`